# Reloading page (ngSubmit) is not working

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a form.

```
<form class="row" style="width: 100%" (ngSubmit)="inf()">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="cups">Yep</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="data" [(ngModel)]="data"
                   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" value="1">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Component Data with inf function

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-info',
  styleUrls: ['./info.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './info.component.html'
})

export class DataComponent {

  public data: string = '1';
  public info;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  inf() {
    console.log("Working");
    this.http.get('http://xxxxxxxx/data/' + this.data, {responseType:     'json'}).subscribe(res => {
      if (Object.keys(res).length > 0) {
        this.info = res;
      } else {
        this.info = null;
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
}
```

If i reload the website and try to search, not working. (Dont show "working" on terminal)

Only working if i go to this template with a internal link routerLink=""

Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'panel', loadChildren: './panel/panel.module#PanelModule' , canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'panel', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'panel' },
];
```

Comment: I'd bet that refreshing your page resets `data`. You are bound to data `[(ngModel)]="data"`. If you enter the page via routing the `data`-object gets filled as usual. Thus, submit will only work if you enter your page via routing. -- Solution: Find a way to refill `data`after page refresh.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I was try without inputs and nothing, ngSubmit not working if i reloaded page.

Comment: Please add your component's typescript code to your post. Do not add it as a comment. ;)

Comment: Added, thanks for your help

Comment: I tested your code on my machine. It's working perfectly. Even after a refresh with CTRL+ R or F5. It seems to be a problem on your side. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Im using Chrome, is it the problem?
im using subroutes  (edited post)